# Jquery popup resizable parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing jquery codes. But I have a problem now. When I write these codes, I want to turn off resizable options of the popup window. But it isn't. What can I do ?

Jquery Codes

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
        <!--
        function popupfs(url)
        {
            alert($(window).width());
         params =  'top=0, left=0'
            if($(window).width() < 1200){
                params += ', width='+(962)+', height='+(656);
            }else if($(window).width() > 1200 && $(window).width() < 1550){
                params += ', width='+(1100)+', height='+(750);
            }else if($(window).width() > 1550){
                params += ', width='+(1547)+', height='+(1055);
            }
         params += ', directories=no';
         params += ', location=no';
         params += ', menubar=no';
         params += ', resizable=no';
         newwin=window.open(url,'windowname4', params);
         if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
         return false;
        }// -->

      </script>
```

HTML Codes

```
<body>  
        <div id="external" >

        </div>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popupfs('2/index.html')">Ekranın Ortasına Popup Açma</a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox 3, [all windows are resizable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_functionality_features) ([take a look at the Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177838)).

[The same happens on Google Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=185425).

That's because that behavior was completely harmful, and against usability. Imagine if someone who changes the default browser's font-size (or even SO font-size): he won't see your content correctly.